# How to loop django model in javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've encountered a small problem but I believe it should be easy to resolve. I pass django model as the context to my template. Model has id/title etc. I can't itterate it in my template via JS as it throws the reference error.

```
(index):53 Uncaught ReferenceError: reservations is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):53)
```

views.py

```
res = []
res.extend([x.movie for x in reserved.reservations.all()]) #// movie is the model
context={
    "user_info":user_info,
     "reserved":set(res)
}
```

template:

```
function reservations() {
    const all_reserved = {{ reserved|safe }}

    for (x=0; x < all_reserved.length; x++) {
        console.log(all_reserved[x].title)
    }
}
```

Comment: A set in Python looks like this: `{"one", "two", "three"}`. Does that look like something you can dump into JavaScript and have it understood?

Comment: But that's just a guess. What does "it throws the reference error" mean? Please give the _exact_ error message. Please read [ask].

Comment: I put set because models name can repeat and I need just the single name from each. Also I just edited the question adding the error message.

Comment: Are there other errors above that? Maybe a `SyntaxError`? In any case, if you're going to dump a variable into the middle of a JavaScript function you need to make sure it is parseable by JavaScript.

Comment: Well visual studio cleary states that {{reserved|safe}} is the syntax error. When I put it into the brackets and then try to print it in console, it prints. But it doesn;t work for loop because it iterates each single letter.

Comment: Ok I could print the models after serializing the passed context variable. Now I need to access the fields.

Comment: How about `<script type="text/javascript">var all_reserved  = "{{ reserved|safe }}"</script>` ?

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski already resolved ;) Also I used "safe" along withj serialization to json and worked for me :) Thanks anyway !

Comment: @czyngis, if you've solved your problem consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This is permitted and encouraged. If you don't want to do that, consider deleting your question instead of leaving it open.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

serialization to json format "reserved":serializers.serialize("json", set(res))
After that it was enough to add |safe to my django variable. Thanks to everyone who attempted to help me :)